# Search for 'ipxe' (PXE bootloader) yields results for 'ipx' (A newtork protocol)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I ran a search for [ipxe](https://serverfault.com/search?q=ipxe) (which is a PXE bootloader), and the results include things like 'ipx', which is something very different.

Can this get fixed so that a search for ipxe & ipx each return their own unique results?

Answer (score 8):

Quotes are your friend ["ipx" (32 results)](https://serverfault.com/search?q=%22ipx%22) ["ipxe" (27 results)](https://serverfault.com/search?q=%22ipxe%22) [ipxe (92 results)](https://serverfault.com/search?q=ipxe).

Comment: Yup.  The default for search is "substring" (plus or minus some fuzz, tags, etc.) if you want something specific `"quote"` it, If you want a tag `[tag]` it...

Answer (score 5):

StackExchange [replaced the search engine a few months ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange). Among the many changes are how string and substring searches are handled.

> - Quoted phrases are ***exact*** matches except for case-sensitivity, for example, [you can search for code][4] or [symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22*=%22).
> - If not in a quoted phrase, words will now be stemmed ([example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=stem%20test))

As @Iain said earlier, quoting matters.